# Powershell doesn't read files size correctly if these are in progress of change (i.e files being downloaded)

Tags: powershell, filesize, ntfs

I am crafting a Powershell script that aims to turn off a Windows machine (laptop/PC) once a download of one or more files is completed (for the sake of the example, let's assume one large file is the case here).

In few words, we're reading the size of the entire downloads folder each x seconds and we compare the before and after delay sizes. If there is no change in the recent time, that means the download is either completed or stuck, both cases lead to shutdown.

Given the following script (the size getter can be a standalone function at some point, yes):

```
#Powershell5
#Major  Minor  Build  Revision
# -----  -----  -----  --------
# 5      1      19041  1320  

$downloadDir = "C:\Users\edi\Downloads"

while (1) 
{
    $s1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $downloadDir | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Select-Object Sum
    write-host "S1:" $s1.sum

    # this 3 seconds time is just for testing purposes; in real case scenario this will most
    # likely be set to 60 or 120 seconds.
    Start-Sleep -s 3

    $s2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $downloadDir | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Select-Object Sum
    write-host "S2:" $s2.sum

    if ($s1.sum -eq $s2.sum) 
    {
        write-host "Download complete, shutting down.."
        # loop exit is this, actual shutdown; commented out for testing purposes.
        #shutdown /s
    } 
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the file sizes reading is not done "in real time". In other words,  the file size is not changing as you would normally see in Explorer view. I need to be able to read these numbers (changing file size) in real time.

**Interesting fact:** while the download is in progress and the script running, if manually going to the downloads folder and hit F5 / Refresh... the numbers change (the size reading is accurate).

**Side note:** My research got me to this article that might present the root cause, but I am not 100% sure of it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813

Appreciate any idea on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest adopting a different strategy:

- Set an overall timeout for each download process, such as `curl.exe`'s `--max-time` option.
- Unfortunately, PowerShell's own `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` appear to have only a *connection* timeout (`-TimeoutSec`), not a timeout for the overall connection.

That way you can track the download *processes*, and trigger a reboot once all of them have terminated (whether due to completion or timeout).

---

As for **your approach**:

- The **on-disk file size** that you can query via `Get-ChildItem` is not updated *continuously* while a file is being written, as you've observed, and while it is ***eventually* updated**, that **may not happen until the file has been *closed*, i.e. written *in full***.

  - You can experiment with throttled writes based  on [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).
- However, **you can update the file-size information *on demand*, namely via the [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Refresh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Refresh) method**, which is the equivalent of the manual refreshing you performed via File Explorer.

  - Note, however, that this still isn't *real-time* size information due to *internal buffering* of writes.

```sh
# Perform this before every Measure-Object call.
# It refreshes the size information of all files in the specified dir.
(Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $downloadDir).Refresh()
```

As an aside: As Santiago points out, this approach fundamentally wouldn't work for download utilities / APIs that *preallocate* the output file with the full size of the download, which is a feature that some BitTorrent clients apparently offer.

As for narrowing down what downloads have completed vs. which ones are assumed to be stuck:

`Invoke-WebRequest` / `Invoke-RestMethod` exclusively lock their output files while a download is ongoing, so you can make a read attempt to see which files cannot be read from, from which you can infer what downloads, if any, are still ongoing:

```sh
# Note: In PowerShell (Core) 7+, use -AsByteStream instead of -Encoding Byte
Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $downloadDir | 
  Get-Content -Encoding Byte -First 1 -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Out-Null

if ($errs) { Write-Warning "Incomplete downloads:`n$($errs.TargetObject)" }
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is meant to demonstrate that, *even though unreliable*, file size can be monitored in real-time. In this case [`[System.IO.StreamWriter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0) is appending data to a file in a separate job while the main thread monitors the current folder size.

I have also performed the same test [while downloading a "test file"](https://fastest.fish/test-files) and it's working fine for me, the total size of the folder is being properly updated.

The possible causes for what you're observing and purely based on assumptions:

- The file being download has pre-allocated space - I don't see how that would be possible since, as you explained, by looking on Explorer you can see the file size increasing.
- There is not enough time between the *size before* vs the *size after* calculation - This could be due to buffering, [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70416272/15339544) has explained this in detail. Increasing the sleep time might solve this problem. Also, calling the [`.Refresh()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh?view=net-7.0), as explained in his helpful answer, might help.

My thoughts, I personally don't think this is the right approach to solve this problem. Process monitoring would be a much better approach (assuming this is a possibility - also explained by mklement0 and I totally agree with him).

```bash
function Get-FolderSize {
    param($Path = $PWD)

    ($Path | Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
}

$startingSize = Get-FolderSize

$job = Start-Job {
    try {
        $chunk   = 'a' * 10kb
        $tmpFile = Join-Path $PWD -ChildPath "testfile.dump"
        $writer  = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $tmpFile
        $writer.AutoFlush = $true

        foreach($i in 0..200kb) {
            $writer.WriteLine($chunk)
        }
    }
    finally {
        $writer.Dispose()
        $tmpFile | Remove-Item
    }
}

try {
    do {
        $sizeBefore = Get-FolderSize
        $waitId     = [Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny($job.Finished, 5000)
        $sizeAfter  = Get-FolderSize

        '[StartSize {0, -5} | SizeBefore {1, -10} | SizeAfter {2, -10}]' -f @(
            $startingSize
            $sizeBefore
            $sizeAfter
        )
    }
    while ($waitId -eq [Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout)
}
finally {
    $job | Stop-Job -PassThru | Remove-Job
}
```

Results for me:

```
[StartSize 11270 | SizeBefore 11270      | SizeAfter 400391534 ]
[StartSize 11270 | SizeBefore 400391534  | SizeAfter 847762094 ]
[StartSize 11270 | SizeBefore 847762094  | SizeAfter 1349824934]
[StartSize 11270 | SizeBefore 1349824934 | SizeAfter 1744551614]
[StartSize 11270 | SizeBefore 1744551614 | SizeAfter 11270     ]
```

Comment: While adding `-File` for conceptual clarity is a good idea, note that directories among the `Get-ChildItem` output objects are simply _ignored_ for the purpose of measuring the `.Length` property. Also, your test isn't quite the same as the OP's scenario, because you're growing the file by repeatedly closing and reopening the file.

Comment: @mklement0 I changed the job's code for something more appropriate

Comment: Thanks - that is a better simulation, though, if a throttle the writes to better simulate  a download (which is usually slower than a  local write), I do see Eduard's problem: the file size isn't updated until after the file is closed and has been written in full. Calling `.Refresh()` on the `FileInfo` instances first solves that problem (although not fully in real-time, due to buffering).

Comment: @mklement0 yeah I see what you mean and fully agree, my answer was more to prove a point than to solve a problem, I didn't agree with `until ($increasingSizeBefore -eq $increasingSizeAfter)` to understand if a download has been completed to begin with but still used it for the example. Calling _sleep_ to compare  _SizeBefore_ vs _SizeAfter_ requires tweaking (and is still prone to failures) and even more if it's a download due to buffering as you already pointed out in addition to calling `.Refresh()` wasn't aware of this one so thanks.

Comment: Yeah, tracking the size growth is not a great approach; if you make the intervals large enough I suppose it will work well enough, if you don't mind spending extra time waiting. Ideally, you'd track the download processes themselves, but they'd have to have their own overall timeouts; `curl.exe` supports that, but neither `Invoke-WebRequest` nor `Invoke-RestMethod` do (they only have timeouts for how long establishing the _connection_ takes).

Comment: @mklement0 yes, I agree that monitoring the process is the right approach, as for `iwr` and `irm` he could use runspace and monitor the instance (that would be another alternative). As for the programs that do a pre-allocation of the file before downloading it, that's a good problem to solve hehe but programs that do that already come with a "shutdown when completed" option...

Comment: I'd forgotten about the preallocation aspect - do you know of specific tools that do that? Note that monitoring `iwr` and `irm` won't help, as you won't know when they have stalled but keep running - you'll have again have to infer stalling from a lack of file growth, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @mklement0 most torrent tools have this option (i.e.: qBittorrent) and it comes as an "optional" so, I was just going about noting that as _something that can happen // to consider_ since these are the kind of topics that really interest me lol